# Python equivalent of php's foreach($array as $key => &$value)

Tags: python, for-loop

is there any equivalent to this PHP notation, which changes the original array (be aware of reference operator)?

```
// increase value of all items by 1
foreach ($array as $k => &$v) {
    $v++;
}
```

I know only this way, which is not so elegant:

```
for i in range(len(array)):
    array[i] += 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
newArray = [i + 1 for i in array]
```

Comment: this is fine if your lists are small, but if you deal with a large amount of data, you want to avoid allocating a second list

Comment: That is true,  for larger lists,  we will have to compromise fancy code for efficiency :)

Comment: But I still think list comprehension would be faster than using enumerate.  But I guess that depends on how list comprehension works internally.

Comment: ranaman MS: I didn't do benchmarks, but enumerate uses iterators so the memory footprint should be lower than with the list comprehension. If memory is not an issue, the comprehension is most likely faster.

Answer (score 67):

When the built in [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) function is called on a list, it returns an object that can be iterated over, returning a count and the value returned from the list.

```
for i, val in enumerate(array):
    array[i] += 1
```

Comment: Also, PHP's array type works as array, list or dict depending on what you put in it; so `for key,value in dictionary.iteritems():` may apply.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding references.

In python, every value is object, and every 'variable' is reference to the object. Assignment never copies value, it always assigns reference.

So v in `for k,v in enumerate([1,2,3])` is reference too, by default. However most objects of basic 'types' are immutable, therefore when you do `immutable_object_reference += 1` you create new instance of `int` and change `immutable_object_reference` to point to new instance.

When our values are of mutable types, references work same as in PHP:

```
>>> class mutable_pseudoint(object):
...     def __init__(self, d):
...         self.d = d
...     def __iadd__(self, v):
...         self.d += v
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return self.d.__repr__()
...     def __str__(self):
...         return self.d.__str__()
... 
>>> l = [mutable_pseudoint(1), mutable_pseudoint(2), mutable_pseudoint(3), mutable_pseudoint(4)]
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> for k,v in enumerate(l):
...     v += 1
... 
>>> l
[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm unaware of being able to get a pointer to a list item, but a cleaner way to access by index is demonstrated by http://effbot.org/zone/python-list.htm:

```
for index, object in enumerate(L):
    L[index] = object+1
```